# How can I read in fewer parameters than scanf expects?

Tags: c, console, scanf

I have this code that I'm trying to use to get user input. Basically, the user can either give an input, index, and a character, or they can just give an input and an index.

When I try running my program it works if I provide all three, but if I provide just an input and an index then the loop isn't entered. Then if I type that same input and index again it works, and then whatever I input after causes one of the if-checks on `input` inside the loop to exit the program—indicating that `scanf()` isn't reading things as I'd hoped. Perhaps there's a buffer that I'm missing or something? Is there something wrong with the way I set this up?

```
  char input[10] = "";
  int index;
  char c;
  int result;

  while ((result = scanf("%s %d %c", input, &index, &c) != EOF)) {
     // do something
  }
```

Comment: It's way more easier if you read the while line with `fgets` and then parse it with `sscanf`.

Comment: Check your parentheses... Looks like `result` is assigned a boolean (rather than the expected return value from the function call...)

Comment: If you only have 10 characters in your `input` array, you want to make sure you use a width specifier with `%s` to avoid a buffer overflow. E.g. `%9s`

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct approach to achieve this, but I made a simple idea that does the job.

First, acquire the user input with the help of the `fgets` and assign it to a character array. Then, parse the input to the needed variables using the `sscanf` function (reads formatted input from a string source), and validate whether the 3rd input (the char) is filled or not.

I insist you go through the code comments for a better explanation. Here is the approach:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 64

int main(void) {
    char input[MAX_LEN];

    printf("Your input: ");
    
    // Input validation
    if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL) {
        // Failed to get input properly...
    }

    // Required variables to be filled
    char in[10];
    int index;
    char c = 0; // Assigning a null by default

    // Reading a formatted input and parsing
    int ret = sscanf(input, "%9s %d %c", in, &index, &c);

    // Validating the conditions
    if (ret < 2) {
        perror("error: Improper formatting.\n");
        return 1;
    } else if (ret == 2 && c == 0) {
        printf("The char 'c' has no value.\n");
    } else if (ret == 2 && c != 0) {
        printf("The char 'c' has value but failed to parse correctly.\n");
    } else {
        printf("All values passed properly.\n");
    }

    printf("%9s %d %c\n", in, index, c);

    return 0;
}
```